# Footable expand all rows

Tags: jquery, footable

I'm using footable (http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/) and I would like to auto-expand all rows when the screen is resized to mobile screen size. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What does the code for `trigger('footable_expand_first_row')` look like? You may need to duplicate and modify that method.

Comment: There is actually a trigger footable_expand_all, but it just was not mentioned in the documents. So $('.footable').trigger('footable_expand_all'); does the trick.

Comment: So $('table').trigger('footable_expand_all');
$('table').bind('footable_breakpoint', function() { $('table').trigger('footable_expand_all'); }); does the trick. I can't yet answer my own question as I don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('table').trigger('footable_expand_all');

$('table').bind('footable_breakpoint', function(){ 
    $('table').trigger('footable_expand_all'); 
    });
```

does the trick.